# VB.NET equivalent of a nameless variable in C#?

Tags: vb.net, instantiation

In C#, you can do this:

```
new MyClass().MyMethod();
```

The method is executed and the reference is (typically) discarded since no reference to the object is kept.

My question is: Is this possible with VB.NET (.NET v4)?

---

Edit: I suppose this is a better example:

```
new Thread((x) => doSomething()).Start();
```

Is this even possible in VB.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET has stricter rules about the syntax of a statement.  The curly-brace languages allow any expression to also be a statement, simply by terminating it with a semi-colon.  That's not the case for VB.NET.  You can only use this syntax if the method you call is a Function.  Which allows you to use the assignment statement:

```
    Dim result = New Test().Func()
```

If it is a Sub then you'll have to use the assignment statement to store the object reference.  This otherwise has no runtime effect, the reference is optimized away.

Comment: So the short answer is "no", this isn't fully possible (only partially), because of how VB is structured. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I like my answer better.  But, I'm partial.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Hans' answer, you could use a [`With` statement:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
Sub Main
    With New Person("Ahmad")
        .PrintName()
        .Name = "Mageed"
        .PrintName()
    End With
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintName()
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} - Len: {1}", Name, Name.Length)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's not as succinct as C#, but the reference to the object is discarded after `End With`.

Comment: Oh, so you actually *can* have a temporary reference created. This is also good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're explicitly wanting to call a sub and not a function, you can:

```
Call (New obj).Func()
```

Which will anonymously create a new obj, and call its Func() method

Answer (score 1):

You can do lambda functions in VB.NET like this:

```
Dim test = Function (x)
    x.doStuff()
End Function
```

Which would be semantically equivilent to:

```
var test = (x) => x.doStuff();
```

I think the one constraint though is that it must return a result under VB.NET.